# Optimization of function with 2 variables

Tags: matlab

I have this function with all variables in the unit square:

```
(x + y)^(1/2) - 6*y*(x + y)^5 - (x + y)^6 + (x - 1)/(2*(x + y)^(1/2))
```

ezplot yields this figure:

[image: Ezplot of 2 variable function]

I want to numerically find 2 points in this plot: First, the minimum value of x on the green line (that is, approx. (0.11, 0.4)) and second, the maximum value of y on the green line (that is, approx. (0.15, 0.43)). These approximate value are just rough estimates from the figure. How can I retrieve these 2 values numerically in matlab?

Comment: To what precision? Either use 'min'/'max' or else more likely you want something like `fmincon`

Comment: Precision to double is sufficient.

Comment: No I mean like to how many decimal points... I think `fmincon` is your answer though. Give it a try and if you get stuck post what you've tried.

Comment: OK, I am trying fmincon. I have set up the constraint, but what would my objective function be?

Comment: It would be just like your function only change your `*` and `^` for `.*` and `.^` and then instead of `x` and `y` use something like `x(:,1)` and `x(:,2)`

Comment: @Dan I believe the objective function would be `x` for the first point, and `y` for the second point.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin does `fmincon` allow you to pass two inputs to your objective function?

Comment: @Dan I am not sure how to use `fmincon` for this problem. But my point is that you shouldn't optimize the function value. After all it is always 0 on the curve. So perhaps you need an objective function like `[1 0]` to find the minimum `x` and `[0 -1]` to find the maximum `y`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Oh I see you meant two separate calls to fmincon - I agree.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Thanks for your hint! That x is the objective function, did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ezplot. You need the handle.

> ```
> h = ezplot('(x + y)^(1/2) - 6*y*(x + y)^5 - (x + y)^6 + (x - 1)/(2*(x + y)^(1/2))', [0 1]);
> ```

Get the data.

> ```
> data = get(h, 'ContourMatrix')
> ```

Remove first column

> ```
> data = data(:,2:end)
> ```

You have what you need. First row are 'x' values and second row are 'y' values.

> ```
> x_min = min(data(1,:));
> y_max = max(data(2,:));
> ```

Comment: Nice, note that this finds the minimal plotted point. If accuracy is a concern, you could consider post processing by evaluating al lot of nearby points and checking whether you find a better solution.